# What does quote="" in read.table() do in R?

Tags: r

When `quote = ""`, the help documentation from `read.table()` say it will turn off the quotation characters. 
What does this exactly mean?

If `quote = "'"`, does this mean to escape single quote?
What if set it empty?

Answer (score 1):

It will replace any characters in the `quote` parameter with the escaped equivalent (i.e. prepend a `\`)